# Excel: Display value from list of options if numbers begin with value from options

Tags: excel

We have a list of phone records and would like to display the locations we have been recieving calls from.

Here is an example data set we have now.

```
 08/02/2013 12:36   441175085086    ANSWER  198
 21/02/2013 15:51   441188398839    CANCEL  0
 26/02/2013 19:11   anonymous   ANSWER  21
 05/03/2013 12:24   441144939783    ANSWER  61
 07/03/2013 15:35   441144583012    ANSWER  324
```

Now we now have another sheet that effectively contains all the prefixes and area codes

```
 44113  Leeds
 44114  Sheffield
 44115  Nottingham
 44116  Leicester
 44117  Bristol
 44118  Reading
```

Now the idea is, that we would like to simply display the area name. However if it does not match the beginning of the prefix list, then it will just be 'Anonymous'

Desired results are:

```
 08/02/2013 12:36   441175085086    ANSWER  198 Bristol
 21/02/2013 15:51   441188398839    CANCEL  0   Reading
 26/02/2013 19:11   anonymous   ANSWER  21  Anonymous
 05/03/2013 12:24   441144939783    ANSWER  61  Sheffield
 07/03/2013 15:35   441144583012    ANSWER  324 Sheffield
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`VLOOKUP()` I believe is the right function for this.

Assuming that you want the area names in column E in Sheet1 as from row 2, the phone numbers are in columnB of that same sheet and the table with prefix and area code in Sheet2 columns A and B, you can use:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2,5), Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

`LEFT(B2,5)` extracts the first 5 characters from the phone number stored in B2. If there are area codes of different lengths, then the formula will have to be revised and it will be much more complex.

`Sheet2!A:B` is the table to lookup the data

`2` is the index of the column containing the values you want to get (the first index is the column containing the area codes)

`FALSE` means exact match. I don't think you'd like to get the area code immediately smaller than the one you're looking for, because you won't be able to get the anonymous people.

Now, you'll get `#N/A` for those that cannot be found. Wrap the whole formula in an `IFERROR()` like so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2,5), Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE), "Anonymous")
```

And this should do the trick :)

Comment: Also, depending on the default language, you might need to use semicolons instead of commas (i.e. `;` instead of `,`). You'll get errors in case you use the wrong one. I'm not sure myself why there's this difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal candidate for `VLOOKUP`. However, make sure that your lookup values and reference tables have the same type:

[image]

Note the right-alignment of the Prefix (Column H; default for numbers/values). The same for Number (Column C). Using `LEFT(C2,5)` returns a string, which is changed back to a value using `VALUE(..)`.

Since some numbers may not be numbers (like `anonymous`), an included error-check only returns valid phone numbers. If the Prefix list is sorted, a `TRUE` condition `VLOOKUP` is also possible that could return a catch-all "Invalid prefix" if no such prefix exist (for example, from other, international numbers not in your Prefix database).